# Haproxy with SSL doesn't works

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I trying to use the new haproxy with ssl(1.5-dev12). But I have an error with this new feature.

I've installed  with:

```
make TARGET=linux2632 USE_OPENSSL=yes
make PREFIX=/opt/haproxy-ssl install
```

But when I check my config file, I've this error:

> [ALERT] 275/135959 (10998) : parsing [/opt/haproxy-ssl/haproxy.conf:31] : 'bind' : 'ssl' option not implemented.
>   [ALERT] 275/135959 (10998) : parsing [/opt/haproxy-ssl/haproxy.conf:69] : 'server' expects  and [:] as arguments.
>   [ALERT] 275/135959 (10998) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /opt/haproxy-ssl/haproxy.conf
>   [WARNING] 275/135959 (10998) : Proxy 'ha_stats': in multi-process mode, stats will be limited to process assigned to the current request.
>   [WARNING] 275/135959 (10998) : stats socket will not work correctly in multi-process mode (nbproc > 1).
>   [ALERT] 275/135959 (10998) : Fatal errors found in configuration.

And the haproxy -vv command return:

> HA-Proxy version 1.5-dev12 2012/09/10
>   Built without OpenSSL support (USE_OPENSSL not set)

I don't understand why openssl is not set though I haven't any error during installation.

OS: Debian 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
OPENSSL: OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Solved with the install of:

```
libssl-dev
```

And then, new make target, new prefix and its works.

Comment: I tried recreate the problem but it worked when I compiled haproxy. Is it a typo that? I used the following command `make TARGET=linux2628 USE_OPENSSL=1`. Note the change of target and `USE_OPENSSL` instead of `USE_OPNSSL`, but YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install libssl-dev before execute the make command and haproxy with ssl should be works.

Comment: On CENTOS its `openssl-devel`.

Comment: For Centos: yum pcre-devel  and 

yum openssl-devel

Answer (score 0):

You can install latest OpenSSL in both Centos and Ubuntu.

RHEL :

```
yum install -y make GCC Perl pcre-devel zlib-devel
```

Ubuntu :

```
apt-get install build-essential make g++ libssl-dev
```

Now,

```
# wget -O /tmp/openssl.tgz https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2-latest.tar.gz

# tar -zxf /tmp/openssl.tgz -C /tmp

# cd /tmp/openssl-*

# ./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl --libdir=lib no-shared zlib-dynamic

# make

# make install_sw
```

You can check that OpenSSL version by below command,

```
# openssl version
```

OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016